# How can I unit test an object that writes to a printer?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, printing

I'm just getting started with unit testing and my component I'm testing has many methods that will print to a specified printer, such as:

- ConfigureLotAndPrint(string printerID, string lot, int quantity);
- ConfigureLogoAndPrint(string printerID, Image logo);

I'm running into the obvious problem that I don't actually want to print, but I need to specify a valid Windows printer name to the methods to test their functionality.  I can't refactor my object to take a Printer object that I could mock and even if I could, I would still need to unit test the Printer object at some point and I'd run into the same problem.

The only thing I can think of is to install a dummy printer that won't actually do anything.  The various PDF printers out there will all popup and ask for a filename, so that won't work.  What I need is a black hole I can send print jobs to.  Googling has turned up nothing promising so I thought I'd ask here and see what the testing crowd suggested I do?

Anyone done this or have any ideas how you would handle this situation?

Comment: 1. Why can't you refactor your code? 2. Once you do you might need to test the /actual/ printer code with an integration or manual test - but at least most of the logic will be covered by unit tests.

Comment: In order: Lack of time (1 man dev. team), lack of experience, printing is in black-box of 3rd party component and it requires a name of a printer to set page defaults which are required to test other functions of the component.  The straightest path to me unit testing this stuff is a black-hole printer I can use, effectively a mock printer.

Comment: My many <DoTasks>AndPrint() methods maybe are good candidates for refactoring...  They are convenience methods designed to save a user from calling SetSerialNumber(sn), SetLogo(logo), SetQuantity(qty) and finally Print(printerID).  Instead I have ConfigureLabelAndPrint(sn, logo, qty, printerID.)  I could refactor out the configuration bits as private methods (I want to keep my interface as minimal as possible) and then Unit Test them with an accessor and not even worry about testing the ConfigureLabelAndPrint method.  Would code coverage analysis tools correctly report on a scheme like this?